# Process list of PHP arrays to find arrays which contain the same keys/values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a long list of arrays which contain values. I'm trying to write a script that will locate duplicate key/value pairs among the arrays and report back to me so I know which arrays have the same data.

```
$array = array(
    'one' => array('foo' => 'foo', 'baz' => 'baz', 'bar' => 'bar'),
    'two' => array('foo' => 'foo', 'baz' => 'baz', 'nil' => 'nil'),
    'three' => array('foo' => 'foo', 'var' => 'var'),
    'four' => array('var' => 'var', 'nil' => 'nil'),
    'five' => array('bar' => 'bar')
);

// First failed attempt
//call_user_func_array('array_intersect_assoc', $array));
```

The result should be able to identify 2 or more arrays share the same keys and values.

```
array(
    array(
        'keys' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        'values' => array('foo' => 'foo')
    ),
    array(
        'keys' => array('one', 'five'),
        'values' => array('bar' => 'bar')
    ),
    array(
        'keys' => array('one', 'two'),
        'values' => array('foo' => 'foo', 'baz' => 'baz')
    ),
    array(
        'keys' => array('three', 'four'),
        'values' => array('var' => 'var')
    ),
    array(
        'keys' => array('two', 'four'),
        'values' => array('nil' => 'nil')
    ),
);
```

What is the proper way to process these arrays? How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Look at `array_intersect`, that might help.

Comment: You should really rethink your data structures if all keys and values are equal. What should that represent anyways?

Comment: @phihag, I'm processing data coming to my app. I need to find duplicates so they can be fixed or merged together.

Comment: But are the keys always equal to their values? I mean, do you have 'bar' => 'bar? Or you can have 'foo' => 'bar'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it was pretty easy assuming that the values are always strings.

```
$master = array();
foreach($array as $name => $row)
{
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        if(empty($master[$key.$value]))
        {
            $master[$key.$value] = array();
        }
        $master[$key.$value][] = $name;
    }
}
print_r($master);
```

Comment: Clever - you might be able to use `serialize(..)` for more coverage